# How to use onEdit to copy the data to another google sheet file and overwrite the data if the ID is the same?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

[image]

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to copy the data from source sheet to destination sheet. When the data reached the destination sheet, the script able to loop through row 2 in destination sheet to see whether any same ID already existed. If the ID already existed in row 2, then it will overwrite the data in the column, if not, the script will find the last empty column based on row 2 and paste the data there.

So in the screenshot above, since there is no `1004` in destination sheet, then it will paste the data in column E.

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();
  var targetfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11tpC8SNZ5XB35n7GON0St3ZQ37dIbM8UbXRjmkVAeJQ");
  var target_sheet = targetfile.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange(3, ss.getLastColumn() + 1);
  
  if (e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart == 16){
    if (e.value == 'Submit'){
      var source_range = ss.getRange("C4:C14")
      source_range.copyTo(target_range);
      e.range.clearContent()
    } 
  } 
}
```

My current problems are:

- The script is not working when I triggered it in cell `C16` (couldn't find the reason)
- I'm not sure how to add the checking for ID in destination sheet into my script.

**This are my google files**

Source sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12kKQKT2XSdPkJ46LSV9OiI167NKBdwKkpkOtOf_r_jI/edit#gid=0

Destination sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11tpC8SNZ5XB35n7GON0St3ZQ37dIbM8UbXRjmkVAeJQ/edit#gid=0

Hope to get some advice and help from expert. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you must set onEdit as installable trigger as you use spreadhsset read and write operations inside it. Rename it first (onEditInstallable or something similar of your choice) to avoid duplicate trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

I see a couple problems with the existing script:

1. Simple Triggers only have authorization on the container `Spreadsheet`, so to access another `Spreadsheet` you need to create an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable):

```
// Creates an edit trigger for a spreadsheet identified by ID.
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet('source-sheet-id')
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

2. `copyTo()` only works when copying to the same `Spreadsheet`. You would need to use `getValues()` and `setValues()` to copy across spreadsheets. The caveat is that formatting is not copied. You would need to manually format the columns if a new column is filled up.

```
function copyFunction(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var targetfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('dest-sheet-id');
  var target_sheet = targetfile.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var id_table = target_sheet.getRange(2,2,1,target_sheet.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();
  
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C16') {
    if (e.value == 'Submit') {
      var source_values = ss.getRange("C3:C14").getValues();
      for (i = 0; i < id_table[0][i]; i++) {
        if (id_table[0][i] == ss.getRange("C3").getValue()) 
        break;
      }
      target_sheet.getRange(2,i+2,12).setValues(source_values);
      e.range.clearContent();
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Charlos, thanks for your correction and solution, I tried to select `Submit` in cell `C16` but the script is not working. I posted my google sheet links above, hope to get your advise on this

Comment: Edited answer. You need to use your source sheet ID in the ````createTrigger```` function and your destination sheet ID in the ````copyFunction```` function. If it is still not working, please check the executions at [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) and edit your question to include what the errors are. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I forgot about that, it works for me now. Thank you veru much!

Comment: Very much appreciated!